# Update column with index position of item in query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I want to update a query of games in a certain order with the index of where it is.  I want to use a SP for this instead of code because I don't want to send 1000 SQL update queries but instead use in SP to update them.

Below is some pseudo-code of what I would want.  I need the index parameter to be where the game is in the order by/where clause.  Basically the first game of the day would be index 1, and so on.

```
UPDATE Games
Set GameId = 'G' + Index
WHERE EventId = 100
ORDER BY Date, Time
```

Below is a sample table after that query is executed.  Notice the first two is the second day hence why its a larger number then the second row which is the previous day, same thing with time.

**Games Table**

```
Date          Time       GameId      EventId
6/22/2020     9:00 AM    G6          100
6/21/2020     8:00 AM    G2          100
6/21/2020     7:00 AM    G1          100
6/21/2020     9:00 AM    G3          100
6/21/2020     10:00 AM   G4          100
6/22/2020     8:00 AM    G5          100
```

Comment: Can you explain more with some sample data?

Comment: check   [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5f0b4e41a804b9b1a262d11aacdc31d)

Comment: Smart guys, I’ll try this out and see if it works

Comment: "G5" has an index of "5", but it is the first game of the day.  That is inconsistent with your explanation.

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about, G5 is the 5th game in the order by so it will be G5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the index with `row_number()`. In SQL Server would recommend an updateable cte for this: the query is much shorter, and does not need a join (this  avoids a second scan):

```
with cte as (
    select gameId, concat('G', row_number() over(order by date, time)) newGameId
    from games
    where eventId = 100
)
update cte set gameId = newGameId
```

Note that, unlike `+`, `concat()` forces a string context, so there is no need to explictly convert the row number.

Comment: Nice, didnt know you could update a cte like that and it updates an actual table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE with a ROW_NUMBER and then join that back to your table.  Like this you can do the update.

```
WITH cte_rn 
as
(
    select [Date],[Time],[EventId],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date],[Time]) as rn
    from [dbo].[Games]
)

UPDATE g1
SET [GameId] = 'G'+CAST(g2.rn AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM [dbo].[Games] g1
JOIN cte_rn g2
    ON g1.[Date] = g2.[Date] 
    AND g1.[Time] = g2.[Time] 
    AND g1.[EventId] = g2.[EventId] ;
```